# In Primefaces, uploaded files which are stored in a temp directory are not automatically deleted, once they have been read

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, temporary-files

- In my xhtml I use the p:fileUpload tag.
- In my session scoped bean I keep a reference to UploadedFile.

Basically I am doing something like this:

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public void fileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    uploadedFile = event.getFile();
}
```

With a separate button, an action in my session bean is invoked which copies the uploaded file to another location. Basically I am doing this:

```
File fileTo =new File(“/xyz/abc.def”);
Files.copy(uploadedFile.getInputstream(), fileTo.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Now the situation is as follows:

With every upload invocation, a temporary file is created in my temp directory. This is ok.

With every upload invocation, the variable uploadedFile is overwritten by event.getFile(). Therefore a previous instance of UploadedFile is at some time later garbage collected. Primefaces uses under the cover Apache’s FileUpload, which deletes the temporary file if UploadedFile is garbage collected. I can see that this works, so this is okay too. So the scenario is to upload one file after the other. I can see that in the temp directory with each upload a new temp file is created and that after a while (1 minute or so) they are magically removed, i.e. they have been deleted during garbage collection. This works perfectly.

At the moment I invoke my action which copies a previously uploaded file, this specific file is not deleted any more, even when I upload later other files and the variable uploadedFile holds references to other instances. I have tried several other techniques to copy the file, like with Apaches IOUtils or just completely hand made with a while loop by reading and writing the bytes to and from a buffer. No matter what I try, it seems that at the moment I start to read the bytes from the input stream which I obtain from UploadedFile, the temporary file is not deleted any more.

Any ideas what can be wrong. 
I have this behavior with Primefaces Version 3.5 was well as with version 5.2.

Comment: Why don't you **move** it, instead of copying? And tried closing the inputstream?

Comment: @Kukeltje, in my opinion I cannot move the file because the class UploadedFile just provides with method getInputstream() an InputStream and I see no way how to move an input stream to another location.

Yes, I also tried to close the input stream after the copy, but this does not help either. Actually I think it is not necessary to close the InputStream explicitly, because when UploadedFile gets garbage collected, the file is removed anyway (except in my situation after reading it ...). I.e. the described behavior is exactly the same, with explicit close of input stream and without.